# Maven killed - don't know why

Tags: java, grails, maven-2, grails-orm

Often I do **mvn install**, the error:

```
[INFO] Tests Completed in 8212ms ...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Tests passed: 104
[INFO] Tests failed: 0
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Starting integration test phase ...
[INFO]      [copy] Copying 3 files to /home/user/application/target/test-classes
[INFO]   [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to /home/user/application/target/classes
[INFO] Property files: [classpath:xxx]
[INFO] Setting up hooks for XXXX integration
[INFO]      [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/user/.grails/1.x.x/projects/application
[INFO]   [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to /home/user/application/target/classes
[INFO] Property files: [...]
[INFO] Setting up hooks for XXX/GORM integration
Getötet
user@localhost ~/ $
```

exit by Getötet (eng.: killed)
But I don't know why

Any ideas?

Comment: I think inspector Clouseau should look into this Maven murder mystery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven can use a lot of memory.  If it uses too much it could be killed by the OOM Killer in linux.